# Shortpath in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this Recursive File list script which works like a charm.
but as soon as the file path gets too long it throws the error that the `path wasn't found`.

So I have to shorten the path somehow using VBA with some google'ing I found out that I could use `.ShortPath` on the `FSO` but I can't figure out how or in which line of the code.

No matter what I tried I only got errors.

Or is there another way to shorten the path of the `FSO`?

```
Sub ListFiles()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objTopFolder As Object
    Dim strTopFolderName As String
    Dim cstrsave As String
    cstrsave = "U:\"

    'Insert the headers for Columns A through F
    Range("A1").Value = "File Name"
    Range("B1").Value = "File Size"
    Range("C1").Value = "File Type"
    Range("D1").Value = "Date Created"
    Range("E1").Value = "Date Last Accessed"
    Range("F1").Value = "Date Last Modified"
    Range("G1").Value = "Path"

    'Assign the top folder to a variable
    'strTopFolderName = "U:\"



    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the top folder
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strTopFolderName)
    'objTopFolder = objTopFolder.ShortPath

    'Call the RecursiveFolder routine
    Call RecursiveFolder(objTopFolder, True)
    Call export_stdList_in_json_format(cstrsave, FileName)
   End Sub


Sub RecursiveFolder(objFolder As Object, _
    IncludeSubFolders As Boolean) 'On Error Resume Next
    'Declare the variables
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim NextRow As Long

    MsgBox (onjFile)
    'Find the next available row
    NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(NextRow, "A").Value = objFile.Name
        Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = objFile.Size
        Cells(NextRow, "C").Value = objFile.Type
        Cells(NextRow, "D").Value = objFile.DateCreated
        Cells(NextRow, "E").Value = objFile.DateLastAccessed
        Cells(NextRow, "F").Value = objFile.DateLastModified
        Cells(NextRow, "G").Value = objFile.path
        NextRow = NextRow + 1
     Next objFile

    'Loop through files in the subfolders
    If IncludeSubFolders Then
        For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.Subfolders
             Call RecursiveFolder(objSubFolder, True)
        Next objSubFolder
    End If ende: 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

this needs to go before the call of the `RecursiveFolder` function in the main sub

```
    s = objTopFolder.ShortPath
    Set objTopFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(s)
```

and this needs to go in the `RecursiveFolder` function

```
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Shortpath
    s = objFolder.ShortPath
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(s)
    MsgBox (objFolder.path)
```